# unable to get the file from the style library using powershell

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, powershell

Trying to get access the folder and files within the style library using PowerShell in my SP 2013 env.

```
 Add-PSSnapIn Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -ErrorAction 
 SilentlyContinue
 cls

 $weburl= "https://mydms.prod.com/sites/dmsHome/"
 $sitee = Get-SPSite $weburl
 $web = Get-SPWeb  $weburl

 #$file =Get-Item $FilePath
 $stylelib  =  $web.lists["Style%20Library"]

 $stylelib.name

 $stylelib.title
 pause
 foreach ($file in $folder.Files) 
  {
      Write-Host "inside foreach,...."
      $file.Url + "---" + $file.name
      pause
  }
 pause
```

Comment: Try to run without the html encode for a blank space (%20) like $web.lists["Style Library"]

Comment: Or, try to actually assign `$folder` a value before trying to iterate over it

Comment: And i don't think you need to get the spsite object to get the web, just go for the web directly.

Answer (score 1):

The following will iterate all files in the root of your style library.

```
Add-PSSnapIn Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
cls

$web = Get-SPWeb "https://mydms.prod.com/sites/dmsHome/"

$stylelib  =  $web.lists["Style Library"]

write-host "Title:"$stylelib.title

foreach ($file in $stylelib.RootFolder.Files)
{
  Write-Host "inside foreach,...."
  $file.Url + "---" + $file.name  
}
```